# Mercurial: Easy way to see changes from last commit

Tags: mercurial

In Mercurial, I can see my current (uncommitted) changes by running

```
$ hg diff
```

Fine. But after commit, I sometimes want to see this diff again (i.e., the diff of the *last changeset*). I know I can achieve this by

```
$ hg log -l 1
changeset:    1234
tag ...

$ hg diff -c 1234
```

I'm looking for a way to do this in one line.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Use `hg diff -c tip`, or `hg tip -p` (shorter, but works only for tip).

This will work until you pull something, since `tip` is an alias for the most recent revision to appear in the repo, either by local commit or 
pull/push from remote repositories.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I've been looking for. Actually it's `-c tip`, not `-r tip`, but the key point is the tip alias.

Comment: @claasz: Glad it helped, and thanks for the tip. I've updated my answer with the right option.

Comment: There's a handy shortcut in the form of `hg tip -p`, but it amounts to the same thing, and the solution given here will work for *any* revision.

Answer (score 16):

You can use relative revision numbers for the `--change` option:

```
hg diff -c -1
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3547662/239247 for more info.

Answer (score 8):

An alternative is to use: `hg diff --rev -2:-1`

This form has the advantage that it can be used with the `status` command (e.g. `hg st --rev -2:-1`), and using it makes it easy to remember what to do when one needs to determine differences between other revision pairs (e.g. `hg diff --rev 0:tip`).

Comment: What is the name of  this syntax? I would like to read more about it. Even better, I would like to be able to open a help or man page about this in command line when I need it, since I need it rarely and often forget this syntax, but I don't know what to search for.

Comment: @islijepcevic - you could call it a revset range.Google: hg revision syntax

Answer (score 5):

The answer from Macke is quite helpful, but in my case I didn't want to diff tip.

Thankfully you can also just diff the currently selected comment:

```
hg diff -c .
```